# System Catalog Information Functions and tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In postgres to get the definition of a constraint you need to call pg_get_constraintdef(constraint_oid) function, that will give you a part of SQL code  (so you can put it in ALTER TABLE statement). Or for example pg_catalog.pg_indexes table in which DDL for indexes is stored. So my quesion is: are there any such funtions/tables in MySQL/MariaDB with DDL code (I know about SHOW CREATE TABLE, but it's not exactly what I want (I can't simply put it in the query to create new constraint or index or whatever)).
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: MySQL has tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `mysql` that may be similar. But I don't think there's anything that returns the data in the form of a DDL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL stores metadata in two databases: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (I think this follows the SQL standard) and `mysql` (this contains MySQL-specific metadata, such as usernames). But none of the data in these tables is in the form of DDL code, so it doesn't satisfy your need. I don't think there's anything in MySQL equivalent to what you describe.